# why doesn't this regular expression get recognized by codeigniter's router

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, url-routing

I have this route:

```
$route["((parameter|type|something)-([0-9]+)\/)+"] = 'somecontroller';
```

so when i test the url with this:

```
www.somewebsite.com/parameter-1/
```

codeigniter returns with a page not found error.  But I tested the regular expression here:

http://rubular.com/

and it seems to work perfectly fine.

Edit:  I have also tried putting the leading/trailing /'s:

```
$route["/((parameter|type|something)-([0-9]+)\/)+/"] = 'somecontroller';
```

Edit:  Ok thanks to Omega(user), it's because the slash character(/) has special precedence or effect in the codeigniter's route parsing engine.  So if it's part of the regular expression you have express how many times it can appear, not sure why, so you can follow it by these operators {}  or ?  or * or +, or any other operator that deals with how many times the preceding expression appears.  So the above route, with the ? operator works:

```
$route["/((parameter|type|something)-([0-9]+)\/)+/?"] = 'somecontroller';
```

It's clearly a codeigniter specific issue.

Comment: Does CI expect you to provide the [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) as well?

Comment: Hmm not sure what you mean, can you explain further please?

Comment: `$route['/((parameter|type|something)-([0-9]+)\/)+/'] = 'somecontroller';` - note the leading/trailing `/`s, and see the link in my first comment

Comment: ok so i added the / in begining and end of the expression, so its now:/((parameter|type|something)-([0-9]+)\/)+/  but it still didn't work

Comment: any suggestiosn would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add `?` to the pattern >> `((parameter|type|something)-([0-9]+)\/?)+`

Comment: Explanation telling the OP why would be nice

Comment: tru, and i tried the ?, but still didn't work.  Honestly, if codeigniter has a specific regex it follows, it should be mentioned in their user guide, i don't see how they can leave that out...

Comment: oh wow, ur right, the ? did the trick, so its basically to escape the slash?

Comment: Slash at the end of path is optional